# OS X open my old version program(test0.1.0.app) when I click it's user notification. Why?

Tags: macos, xcode5, nsusernotificationcenter

There are several version programs in my mac. Test0.1.0.app, Test0.2.0.app and Test0.4.0.app which i build it just now with xcode5.0.

Test0.1.0.app in somewhere.

Test0.2.0.app in somewhere.

Test0.4.0.app in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/..../Debug/Test0.4.0.app.

I add NsUserNotification in Test.app.

I open Test0.4.0.app and wait for a notification arrive. Then I close Test0.4.0.app and click the notification(top-right corner), it will open Test0.2.0.app.

Why? How can I control the notification to open specific version test.app?

Comment: Try adding the old versions of the app to Spotlight’s ignore list in System Preferences. Also try [rebuilding Launch Services](http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/rebuild-launchservices-fix-duplicate-entries-os-xs-open-menu/). Not posting as an answer because I don’t know if these will help. I believe the fact that the apps share a bundle identifier may be the underlying cause.